# Specify individual y axis limits independent of content - pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I'd like to draw the y axis on the left with independent limits compared to the drawn content of the plot.

I've chosen the pgfplots tutorial as MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line = none,
        axis y line = left]
\addplot [
scatter,
only marks,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
scatter/classes={
a={mark=square*,blue},
b={mark=triangle*,red},
c={mark=o,draw=black}% <-- don't add comma
},
] table [meta=label] {
x y label
0.1 0.15 a
0.45 0.27 c
0.02 0.17 a
0.06 0.1 a
0.9 0.5 b
0.5 0.3 c
0.85 0.52 b
0.12 0.05 a
0.73 0.45 b
0.53 0.25 c
0.76 0.5 b
0.55 0.32 c
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and used PowerPoint to add the desired y axis (blue), e.g. draw it from 0.15 to 0.45 compared to the current black one that is generated by pgfplots:

[image]

I don't want to adjust the limits of the plot, as it fits the data well.
Do I have to draw my y axis separately or is there a way to specify the limits?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can just shorten the axis line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line = none,
        axis y line = left,
        ytick={0.2,0.3,0.4},
        axis line style={shorten >=0.8cm,shorten <=1cm}
        ]
\addplot [
scatter,
only marks,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
scatter/classes={
a={mark=square*,blue},
b={mark=triangle*,red},
c={mark=o,draw=black}% <-- don't add comma
},
] table [meta=label] {
x y label
0.1 0.15 a
0.45 0.27 c
0.02 0.17 a
0.06 0.1 a
0.9 0.5 b
0.5 0.3 c
0.85 0.52 b
0.12 0.05 a
0.73 0.45 b
0.53 0.25 c
0.76 0.5 b
0.55 0.32 c
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and easy solution that helped me much in the first place!

Do you see a chance to specify the shortening in terms of y axis values? The cm spec is output dependent.